# Switching textures of renderers in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, textures, renderer

I am creating a character customization system. I have 2 shirts with their own 2 textures.

When I switch shirts the all of the textures are applying **two both renderers instead of their own**.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my script.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharCustomizationOne : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] characters;

    public GameObject[] maleHairs;
    public GameObject[] maleShirts;
    public GameObject[] malePants;

    public GameObject[] femaleHairs;
    public GameObject[] femaleShirts;
    public GameObject[] femalePants;

    public Texture[] charTexturesM;
    public Texture[] charTexturesF;

    public Texture[] shirtTextureM;
    public Texture[] shirtTextureF;

    public Texture[] pantTextureM;
    public Texture[] pantTextureF;

    private int currentCharacters;

    private int currentMaleHair;
    private int currentMaleShirts;
    private int currentMalePants;

    private int currentFemaleHair;
    private int currentFemaleShirt;
    private int currentFemalePant;

    private int currentCharTextureM;
    private int currentCharTextureF;

    private int currentShirtTextureM;
    private int currentShirtTextureF;

    private int currentPantTextureM;
    private int currentPantTextureF;

    public Renderer rendererM;
    public Renderer rendererF;

    public Renderer[] rendererShirtM = new Renderer[2];
    public Renderer[] rendererShirtF = new Renderer[2];

    public Renderer[] rendererPantM = new Renderer[2];
    public Renderer[] rendererPantF = new Renderer[2];
    public void Update() {

        //Gender Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == currentCharacters)
            {
                characters[i].SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                characters[i].SetActive(false);
            }

        }
        //Hair Loop
        if (currentCharacters == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maleHairs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentMaleHair)
                {
                    femaleHairs[i].SetActive(false);
                    maleHairs[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    femaleHairs[i].SetActive(false);
                    maleHairs[i].SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < femaleHairs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentFemaleHair)
                {
                    maleHairs[i].SetActive(false);
                    femaleHairs[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    maleHairs[i].SetActive(false);
                    femaleHairs[i].SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
        // Shirt Loop


        if (currentCharacters == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maleShirts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentMaleShirts)
                {
                    femaleShirts[i].SetActive(false);
                    maleShirts[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    femaleShirts[i].SetActive(false);
                    maleShirts[i].SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < femaleShirts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentFemaleShirt)
                {
                    maleShirts[i].SetActive(false);
                    femaleShirts[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    maleShirts[i].SetActive(false);
                    femaleShirts[i].SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }



        // Pants Loop

        if (currentCharacters == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < malePants.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentMalePants)
                {
                    femalePants[i].SetActive(false);
                    malePants[i].SetActive(true);
                }

                else
                {
                    femalePants[i].SetActive(false);
                    malePants[i].SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < femalePants.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentFemalePant)
                {
                    malePants[i].SetActive(false);
                    femalePants[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    malePants[i].SetActive(false);
                    femalePants[i].SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }

        //CharTexture Loop

        if (currentCharacters == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < charTexturesM.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentCharTextureM)
                {
                    rendererM.sharedMaterial.mainTexture = charTexturesM[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < charTexturesF.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == currentCharTextureF)
                {
                    rendererF.sharedMaterial.mainTexture = charTexturesF[i];
                }
            }
        }

        //Shirt Texture Loop
        if (currentCharacters == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maleShirts.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < shirtTextureM.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j == currentShirtTextureM)
                    {
                        rendererShirtM[i].sharedMaterial.mainTexture = shirtTextureM[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < femaleShirts.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < shirtTextureF.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j == currentShirtTextureF)
                    {
                        rendererShirtF[i].sharedMaterial.mainTexture = shirtTextureF[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Pant Texture Loop

        if (currentCharacters == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < malePants.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pantTextureM.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j == currentPantTextureM)
                    {
                        rendererPantM[i].sharedMaterial.mainTexture = pantTextureM[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < femalePants.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pantTextureF.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (j == currentPantTextureF)
                    {
                        rendererPantF[i].sharedMaterial.mainTexture = pantTextureF[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }     

    //Switching Characters
    public void SwitchCharacters() {
        Debug.Log("Method Called!");



        if (currentCharacters == characters.Length - 1)
        {
            currentCharacters = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentCharacters++;
        }

        }

    //Switching Hairs
    public void SwitchHairs() {
        Debug.Log("MaleHairsCalled");
        if (currentMaleHair == maleHairs.Length - 1)
        {
            currentMaleHair = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentMaleHair++;
        }



        if (currentFemaleHair == femaleHairs.Length - 1)
        {
            currentFemaleHair= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentFemaleHair++;
        }
    }

    //Switching Shirts
    public void SwitchShirts()
    {
        Debug.Log("MaleShirtCalled");
        if (currentMaleShirts == maleShirts.Length - 1)
        {
            currentMaleShirts = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentMaleShirts++;
        }

        if (currentFemaleShirt == femaleShirts.Length - 1)
        {
            currentFemaleShirt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentFemaleShirt++;
        }
    }

    //Switching Pants
    public void SwitchPants() {
        Debug.Log("MalePantsCalled");
        if (currentMalePants == malePants.Length - 1)
        {
            currentMalePants = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentMalePants++;
        }

        if (currentFemalePant == femalePants.Length - 1)
        {
            currentFemalePant = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentFemalePant++;
        }
    }

    //Switching Character Textures
    public void SwitchCharTexture()
    {
        Debug.Log("Char Texture Method Was Called!");
        if (currentCharTextureM == charTexturesM.Length - 1)
        {
            currentCharTextureM = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentCharTextureM++;
        }

        if (currentCharTextureF == charTexturesF.Length - 1)
        {
            currentCharTextureF = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentCharTextureF++;
        }

    }

    public void SwitchShirtTexture()
    {
        Debug.Log("Shirt Texture Method Was Called!");
        if (currentShirtTextureM == shirtTextureM.Length - 1)
        {
            currentShirtTextureM = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentShirtTextureM++;
        }

        if (currentShirtTextureF == shirtTextureF.Length - 1)
        {
            currentShirtTextureF = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentShirtTextureF++;
        }
    }

    public void SwitchPantTexture()
    {
        Debug.Log("Pant Texture Method Was Called!");

        if (currentPantTextureM == pantTextureM.Length - 1)
        {
            currentPantTextureM = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPantTextureM++;
        }

        if (currentPantTextureF == pantTextureF.Length - 1)
        {
            currentPantTextureF = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPantTextureF++;
        }
    }
    //End of Class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of [`Renderer.sharedMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html)

> Modifying [`sharedMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html)  will change the appearance of **all objects** using this material, **and change material settings** that are stored in the project too.
>
> It is not recommended to modify materials returned by [`sharedMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html). If you want to modify the material of a renderer use [`material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) instead.

rather use [`Renderer.material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html)

> Modifying [`material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) will change the material for this object only.
>
> If the material is used by any other renderers, this will clone the shared material and start using it from now on.

---

Also check your loops .. some things seems odd there e.g.

```c#
for (int j = 0; j < someTextureArray.Length; j++)
{
    if (j == currentTextureIndex)
    {
        someRenderer[i].material.mainTexture = someTextureArray[j];
    }
}
```

seems just to be a very complex way of simply writing

```c#
someRenderer[i].material.mainTexture = someTextureArray[currentTextureIndex];
```

---

For all your switch methods: note that the easiest solution for wrap around a positive counter for indices in an array you can simply do

```c#
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % accordingArray.Length;
```

Comment: I tried using renderer.material. But the output is still the same

Comment: Then also debug your loops e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < maleShirts.Length; i++)` should really both of them being changed?

Comment: I used the loop mentioned in your comment in order to apply change of texture mechanic to both renderer. 
public Renderer[] rendererShirtM = new Renderer[2];